# Android ( Java ): Enable GPS or WiFi with Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, gps, wifi

I´ve a small question. Is it possible to enable Gps with an Intent? I tried `Intent intent=new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);` but this only opens the gps settings, but I want to change (enable/disable) the gps settings.
(sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to enable Gps with an Intent?

No, for privacy reasons. Apps cannot enable GPS, outside of unusual scenarios (e.g., rooted devices).

> I tried Intent intent=new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS); but this only opens the gps settings

Correct. The user can choose whether or not to enable or disable any of the location providers on that screen.

If you are willing to be dependent upon Play Services, they added a `SettingsApi` in the 7.0.0 release that allows you to pop up a simpler dialog for the user to elect whether or not to enable locations, though the effect is largely the same as with `ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS`.